# How to set different images alternately in listView's row?

Tags: android

I have a listview, in which I am fetching data from Twitter, I also show it in listView,
but I want to show different images in different rows of listView.

I used `convert-view.setBackGroundResource(R.drawable.strip1);`, it repeats this image in all rows, but I want to set it alternatively. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use an adapter like this, replace List with what you need.

```
/**
 * Handles the listView.
 */
private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Call> {

    private ArrayList<List> items;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<List> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the View populated with data.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }
        List l = items.get(position);
        if (l != null) {
            ImageView ci = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_listIcon);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your image from what criteria ?

For example you can do something like :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyCell resultView = (MyCell) convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MyActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mycell, null);
    }
    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        convert-view.setBackGroundResource(R.drawable.strip1);
    } else {
        convert-view.setBackGroundResource(R.drawable.strip2);
    }
    return resultView;
}
```

To have different background based on the cell's position parity.

Answer (score 0):

use the position in:

```
getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

and do something like this

```
if(position%2 == 0) {
    convert-view.setBackGroundResource(R.drawable.strip1);
} else {
    convert-view.setBackGroundResource(R.drawable.strip2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [List14](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) which is an example of exactly that. It's using your own custom adapter and then they alternate the pictures depending on the position, in this case if it's an even or odd row.

Take a look at this part of the getView method:

```
// Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
        holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);
```